# Not loading page

Tags: jquery

What I'm wanting to do is after I get the ajax request back that from the server and it was a success I want it to show the div.valid_box with the data.message inside of it with the proper css applied which it all does but afterwards I need it to just simply load the new page called index.php which is the admin panel page but it does not. Any ideas why?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processes/login.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.errorsExist) {
            $('div.valid_box').hide();
            $("div.error_box").html(data.message).css("margin-left", "145px").css("width", "520px").show(); 
        } else {
            $('div.error_box').hide();
            $("div.valid_box").html(data.message).css("margin-left", "145px").css("width", "520px").show().delay(10000).hide("slow", function() {
                $('body').load('index.php');  
            });    
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
window.location.href = "index.php";
```

instead of

```
$('body').load('index.php');
```

Comment: i keep getting this an an error:   $("div.valid_box").html(data.message).css("margin-left", "145px").css("width", "520px").show().delay is not a function
[Break On This Error] $(...elay(10000).hide("slow", function() {